# How to convert a decimal number to the base in which it has minimum value?

Tags: python, c, math, radix

In a coding contest I was given a number in decimal and was asked if this number can have minimum value in any other base, if yes then convert it.
E.g. let a decimal number be `234` then can we convert this into other bases in which it has minimum value?

Comment: Changing the base in which a number is written doesn't change the value of that number. You'll have to clarify what you're interested in.

Comment: The base can't be smaller or equal than the smallest digit `d`. A greater base value means the same digits will sum with greater values and hence the smallest base should be `d+1`.

Comment: @a_guest the sum is wrong metric (1000 vs 2),  number of digits is better along with leading digits value in case of same digits count numbers. that is what the d+1 base is about. So you are basically right just used wrong metric wording ...

Answer (score 4):

I assume that you're given a sequence of digits and need to determine the base in which that sequence of digits has the smallest value. Since the base needs to be greater than the largest digit but larger base values also mean larger values for each of the digits (save for one-digit numbers), the minimum base is `d_max + 1` where `d_max` is the largest digit:

```
def min_base(s: str) -> int:
    return max(int(x) if x.isdigit() else ord(x) - 87 for x in s.lower()) + 1

print(min_base('12345'))  # 6
print(min_base('1A2B'))  # 12
print(min_base('BCA'))  # 13

# OP's example:
print(int('234', base=10))  # 234
print(int('234', base=min_base('234')))  # 69
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of arbitrary bases any integer number has its minimal (single digit) value in any base bigger to it ...

```
????? (base=10) = ? (base ????+1)
```

examples:

```
15 (base = 10) = F (base 16)
16 (base = 10) = G (base 17)
17 (base = 10) = H (base 18)
...
```

Of coarse once you hit the end of alphabet there is no standardized convention how the digits values should be named (Above `Z` ... base > 10+26) sometimes Greek alphabet is used.

If you have fixed list of bases to convert to instead then bases less than or equal to your value produce multi digit numbers. The lesser the base the more digits. The ratio between integer digits and their bases are constant so you can compute it without actualy convert the number:

```
digits_base1 / digits_base_2 = log(base_2) / log(base_1)
digits_base1 = digits_base_2 * log(base_2) / log(base_1)
```

example:

```
   31 dec -> 2 digits  (base 1)
11111 bin -> 5 digits  (base 2)

2 = ceil(5 * log(2) / log(10))
2 = ceil(5 * 0.30102999566398119521373889472449 / 1)
2 = ceil(1.5051499783199059760686944736225)
2 = 2     // so 5 digit binary number has 2 digits in decimal
```

So simply start checking the bases from biggest to smallest in the list and once the digit number increase use previous base ...